# SSIS not exporting dates and money types to flat file as correctly formatted string

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, ssis-data-types

I am exporting a file that is going to be picked up by another system. To avoid rework in the other system I am trying to match an existing excel csv output exactly. I have a date column in the DB which I want to export as dd/mm/yyy. In the data flow task I have the following SQL as the source where I do the appropriate conversion. If I run this query in ssms I get the right output.

```
SELECT [Code]
      ,[Agency_Name]
      ,[Region_Group]
      ,CONVERT( varchar(20), [GrossAmtYrly] , 1) GrossAmtYrly
      ,CONVERT ( varchar(20), [SaleDate] , 103) SaleDate
      ,[MemberNo]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[Scale]
  FROM [Land].[Sales]
```

I then link this to a flat file destination, the column that this is mapped to is set to DT_SR width 20 not text qualified.

But the output file is spitting out a date in format yyyy-mm-dd.

Similarly for the grossamtyrly the old excel generated csv had the amount with commas after each 3 digits, wrapped in ". The output column it is mapped to is DT_SR width 20 with text qualified to true.

The output file for that column is missing the commas for grossamtyrly.

So it seems like my conversions in the SQL are being ignored completely, but I can't work out why.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Using SSIS 2012 - Visual Basic 2010, DB is SQL Server 2012

Comment: try changing on the source -> advanced editor -> input and output -> oledb source output -> output columns -> then on the change the output dataType to be dt_dbdate instead of dt_dbtimestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Custodian, I figure out how to get it to work.

I double clicked on the flow arrow between the tasks and the metadata tab shows the data type of each column. When I first set this up I did access mode as table or view and so date and grossamt were set to DT_DATE and DT_CY, so I think SSIS was implictly converting the column back again to its original type.

Now I couldn't work out how to change them, So I deleted the DB Source and recreated it starting with the SQL Command option, and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a derived column in the data flow to convert it to the format you want. If it's coming in as a text field in format yyyy-mm-dd, you can convert it to dd/mm/yyyy with the following expression:

```
SUBSTRING(dt,9,2) + "//" + SUBSTRING(dt,6,2) + "//" + SUBSTRING(dt,1,4)
```